# Can't scrape "span" string element beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the html codes from the website I want to scrape:
[image]

So I want to scrape that `Megapolitan` string from `span itemprop` tag. But I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-ceb296a3cb50> in <module>()
     15     soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
     16 
---> 17     cat = soup.find('span', {'itemprop','name'}).text
     18     content = soup.find('div', {'class','read__content'}).text
     19     times = soup.find('div', {'class', 'read__time'}).text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

From what I know the string is not scraped because even I remove `.text` resulting None. This is my code:

```
kompasurl = ('https://www.kompas.com/', 'https://news.kompas.com/', 'https://www.kompas.com/hype', 'https://www.kompas.com/food')
arti = []
for url in kompasurl:
  kompas = requests.get(url)
  beau = BeautifulSoup(kompas.content)
  news = beau.find_all('div', {'class','most__list clearfix'})
  
  for each in news:
    nu = each.find('div', {'class','most__count'}).text
    title = each.find('h4', {'class','most__title'}).text
    lnk = each.a.get('href')

    rcount = each.find('div', {'class','most__read'}).text
    r = requests.get(lnk)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

    cat = soup.find('span', {'itemprop','name'}).text
    content = soup.find('div', {'class','read__content'}).text
    times = soup.find('div', {'class', 'read__time'}).text

    print(nu)
    print(title)
    print(lnk)
    print(rcount)
    print(times)
    print("")

    arti.append({
      'Top Number': nu,
      'Headline': title,
      'Content':content,
      'Category' : cat,
      'Link': lnk,
      'Date': times,
      'Read Count': rcount
      
    })


df = pd.DataFrame(arti)
df.to_csv('kompas.csv', index=False)
```

I need help for this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: [Here](https://megapolitan.kompas.com/read/2020/11/11/05080981/selasa-malam-anies-temui-rizieq-shihab-di-petamburan) is one of their news article pages that contains html elements I shared above. All of their news article pages have same html elements.

All url from `kompasurl` is the main page of news website. Each news article is not in their main page, but on another page which the links is in the main page.

Comment: Does `kompas.content` contain the span element? If not you need to javascript render first before you scrape.

Comment: The span element that I want to scrap is in the news page from the scraped link from `kompas.content` then stored in `r` variables. All url inside `kompas.content is the main site that contains links of each news article their published. [Here](https://megapolitan.kompas.com/read/2020/11/11/05080981/selasa-malam-anies-temui-rizieq-shihab-di-petamburan) is the one of their news article page which contain html elements I shared above

Comment: Please do the following experiment: `import requests; res = requests.get("https://www.kompas.com/"); print(res.content)` Now search for `span itemprop`. It's not there. Hence my comment. If it is not there you need to javascript render first.

Comment: Because it's not in `kompas.com`, it's on the news article page which the url is from `lnk = each.a.get('href')` then I request the news article from variable that contain the news article url with this code `r = requests.get(lnk)` and use BeautifulSoup with this code `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)`. Them problem is not on the `kompas.com` or all url inside `kompasurl`, but it's from the news article page

Answer (score 0):

A little bit confusing information, but think following is the "point":

```
{'itemprop','name'}
```

Should be devided by `:` not by `,`

**This should work(for first span only)**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests; 

res = requests.get("https://megapolitan.kompas.com/read/2020/11/11/05080981/selasa-malam-anies-temui-rizieq-shihab-di-petamburan"); 
bs = BeautifulSoup(res.content)
cat = bs.find('span', {'itemprop':'name'}).text
print(cat)
```

To get all span of breadcrump or specific eg the third you should adjust your `find`